# If metric circles on a surface are genuine circles, must the surface be sphere?

Tags: differential-geometry, circles, spherical-geometry

A moment's thought (or some careful examination of maps) reveals that any circle drawn on a globe is in fact a circle in real life.  The same claim holds for circles drawn on flat surfaces (obviously).

Are these the only examples?

Formally, let $M$ be any Riemannian surface, (isometrically) embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Moreover, suppose that any metric circle $C$ (i.e., a locus of points with constant geodesic distance from some fixed point) is in fact a circle in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Then must $M$ have constant nonnegative Gaussian curvature?

Comment: This is not quite the setting of your question, but I’ll comment anyhow that geodesic circles in the hyperbolic plane are Euclidean circles (but with different centers).

Answer (score 1):

Yes!

First, note that such a surface must have nonnegative curvature.  For: fix a point $p$.  Working in geodesic polar coordinates about $p$, the group $\mathrm{SO}(\mathbb{R}^2)\cong S^1$ acts on any connected surface by rotating each metric circle.  Since our metric circles are genuine circles, the resulting action is an isometry on some geodesic ball around $p$.  But rotation by $90^\circ$ interchanges the principal curvatures; thus both curvatures are equal.  Since the Gaussian curvature is the product of the two curvatures, it is a perfect square and so nonnegative.

Second, since genuine circles have constant geodesic curvature, [this Q&A thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4176992/330413) proves that $M$ must have constant curvature.

Comment: "Since our metric circles are genuine circles, M is invariant under this action". I guess you wanted to say: "since our metric circles are genuine circles, $SO(2)$ acts by isometries". Because $M$ is invariant by definition of action. Maybe I am not understanding the point

Comment: Why must the curvature be nonnegative?

Comment: In general your $S^1$ action is not defined on the whole surface.

Comment: @AntonioJPan That's exactly what I meant; thanks for the proper phrasing.

Comment: @Didier: If the two principal curvatures are $\kappa_1$ and $\kappa_2$, the Gaussian curvature is $\kappa_1\kappa_2$.  But $\kappa_1=\kappa_2$ here and curvatures are real numbers.

Comment: @ArcticChar: Thanks; I just need it on a neighborhood of $p$, and I've rewritten the sentence to reflect that.

Comment: @JacobManaker I see you have edited. This was not explicit at all!

Comment: @Didier: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/7247/in-a-popular-anecdote-who-took-20-minutes-to-decide-that-a-thing-was-obvious

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the $SO(2)$ action.  If we take two metric circles (of small radius, so they are both near $p$), how do we know that planes containing them (in $\mathbb{R}^3$) are parallel?  If they aren't the $SO(2)$ actions on each metric circle are not compatible, and can't be patched together to get an $SO(2)$ action on the whole neighborhood of $p$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: The action is through the coordinates patch

Comment: @JasonDeVito: Huh?  I'm not sure what patching is necessary.  Any circle has a transitive, free action of $\mathrm{SO}(2)$.

Comment: I agree each circle has a free transitive action which is isometric on each circle.  It's not clear to me that each of these actions comes from one action on the small neighborhood.  I am not saying you're wrong, I just don't see it.

Comment: In more detail:  working in $\mathbb{R}^3$, take a point $p$ in the submanifold $M$.  It seems you're trying to claim that the $S^1$ action on $\mathbb{R}^3$ which fixes $p$ and rotates the tangent plane at $p$ is an isometry of a small neighborhood $U\subseteq M$ of $p$.  But it's not clear to me that the plane containing each metric circle about $p$ in $U$ is parallel to $T_pM \subseteq T_p \mathbb{R}^3$.  If any one of those planes isn't parallel, the $S^1$ action need not map $M$ to itself.

Comment: @JasonDeVito I think what OP is considering is something like, in polar coordinates in a small neighbourhood: $\phi\cdot \exp_p(r \theta) = \exp_p(r(\theta+\phi))$. It is not clear to me that this defines an isometric action of the neighbourhood, I agree with you

Comment: @Didier:  I see.  Do you happen to know of an example of a surface $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ (with metric inherited from $\mathbb{R}^3$)together with an isometry $f:S\rightarrow S$ which does *not* extend to an isometry of $\mathbb{R}^3$?  Bonus points if the isometry is in the identity component of $Isom(S)$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito If you allow drastically non smooth isometric embedding, an embedding of the flat torus would work. As for the smooth case, I have no idea right now